# Turn master page on/off for a webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I know this is a weird situation, but It's something I'll have to do in order not to need the same page twice.

I have a webform that opens via popup, it currently has no master page, because it's opened via the main form.

So, my client told me I'll have to make it open both via this popup, or via a menu near the main form. If I open it via the menu, it'll open like a normal page and need to contain the master page layout.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not likely. If a page is supposed to be a content page with a master behind, it does not contain the whole markup, not even the form. Without master that page simply won't work. What you could do though is have two different master pages, and alternate between them depending on the way the page is being opened. This is very doable

Comment: I think creating a blank master page and set `this.MasterPage = "myBlankMasterPage.cs"` should work, then?

Comment: Not quite sure. Your page needs to change, to begin with, to look similar to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

*Set via code:*

```
 protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnPreInit(e);
      if(xy)
      {  
        this.MasterPageFile = "~/MyMaster.Master"; //Path to masterpage '~' if rootfolder
      }
      else
      {
        this.MasterPageFile = "";
      }
    }
```

*Use UserControl:*

Create a Usercontrol (.ascx) which contains the current page code. Then create a second page (.aspx) with masterpage and register the control on both pages.

Some Information about UserControls:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I had to use a different approach.

I made all the elements on the masterpage (header, footer, menu) to be `runat=server` and set them to invisible where I didn't want the master page layout.

It's obviously a dirty hack, but it worked.